# Textarea, после перевода строки "enter"ом портит массив

Tags: html, textarea, php

В общем, сам код:

```
// предположим что текст пришел с формы html
$a='2015'; $b='text'; $c=$_REQUEST['textarea'];

$k=array($a, $b, $c);
serialize ($k);
```

Выдает такой вот текст:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:16:"2015";i:1;s:15:"тема";i:2;s:42:"test (здесь энтер - разрыв строки!!)
12next string";}
```

Получается, программа работает до того момента, пока в `textarea` не поставить `enter`. Если это сделать, то массив разорвется на две строки и перестает работать. Что можно сделать, чтобы  `ENTER` заменить спецсимволом?

Comment: @zaryad68gmail, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: > Получается программа работает до того момента, пока в texterea не поставить enter.

Да и дальше она тоже вполне себе работает. `unserialize(serialize('test' . PHP_EOL . 'test'));` работает без проблем

Comment: А как заменить энтер на PHP_EOL?

Comment: @zaryad68gmail, в большинстве случае это он и есть /captain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот код решит вашу проблему:

```
$c = str_replace("\r\n", "", $_REQUEST['textarea']); //Windows
$c = str_replace("\n", "", $_REQUEST['textarea']); //Linux
```

Comment: Спасибо! По твоей подсказке помог такой вот код:
 
    @$с=ereg_replace("(\r\n|\n)", "WU_ENTER", $_REQUEST['textarea']);

Comment: @zaryad68gmail, а разве ereg_replace не считается устаревшим?

Comment: @dimka3210, считается в php 5.3.0 и выше, рекомендуется использовать reg_replace.